# Android Studio Instant Run not working

Tags: android-studio, instant-run

I am trying to get Instant Run to work in Android Studio.  I have A.S. 2.0 Preview 4 installed, and my Instant Run is enabled like this:
[image]

Now, I am experimenting with this in the Topeka sample app from Google (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-topeka).  So, I am placing a bunch of Toasts in CategorySelectionActivity and CategorySelectionFragment, hoping that they can be instantaneously changed with Instant Run.  But every time I hit the Instant Run button in A.S., it completely shuts down the app and re-installs it.  It does not resume from the same activity I was on previously (as expected), NOR is it displaying the toast message like

> Applied code changes without Activity restart

Does anyone know how to get Instant Run to work properly?

Thanks,
Igor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is to update Android Studio to **2.0 Preview 8**, gradle wrapper to:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.10-all.zip
```

and to use this gradle dependency:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.0.0-alpha8'
```

Instant run works now on my Mac!

Answer (score 1):

Please update Android Studio to [Android Studio 2.0 Preview 8](http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio20preview8available).Android Studio 2.0 Preview 8 to the canary channel, as well as a new version of the Gradle plugin: 2.0.0-alpha8. You'll want to update both; instant run in particular is only enabled when using the latest versions of both: